# How would secondary Natural Weapons be affected by Dragon's Ferocity

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, natural-weapon

The feat [Feral Combat Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat/) allows you to use feats with the prerequisite of [Improved Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat/improved-unarmed-strike-combat-final) on the selected natural attack.

Assuming I select a secondary natural attack such as a tentacle for the focus of the feat, My question is how would secondary natural attacks, which normally deal only 1/2 Strength bonus to damage, interact with the feat [Dragon's ferocity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dragon-ferocity-combat/) which makes all attacks after the first deal 1 1/2 Strength bonus.

Answer (score 4):

The feat Dragon's Ferocity says.

> Benefit: While using Dragon Style, **increase your Strength bonus on unarmed strike damage rolls by an additional one-half your Strength bonus**, to a total of double your Strength bonus on the first attack and 1-1/2 times your Strength bonus on the other attacks.

The 1-1/2 is an example of using manufactured weapons and not secondary natural weapons. It is not what it sets the damage to, secondary natural attacks would add an additional 1/2 Strength bonus making them deal the full bonus instead of just 1/2.